# Do I need any preposition in front of "the second time"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

I am wondering if I need any preposition in front of "the second time" when I say "do something for/in/at/on the second time"  for example,"I hope you get it ... the second time."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The omission or inclusion of the preposition **for** really depends on the context and what you want to say. For example, the following sentences mean different things:

> He succeeded for the second time

tells you that he has succeeded twice, while

> He succeeded the second time

indicates that he failed the first time and has only succeeded once.

In your examples, you can either omit or include **for**.

> I hope you get it the second time

implies that the person did not get it the first time.

> I hope you get it for the second time

implies that you hope the person gets it once again, although if you insert a comma, thus:

> I hope you get it, for the second time

you indicate in an irritated manner for the second time that you hope the person gets it.